# Does std::vector.reserve() erase existing values?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a vector full of, idk lets say `Rectangles` with type x,y,w,h. And now I want to add 10000 more to my existing 10000, will calling `vector.reserve(20000)`delete my existing 10000 rectangles?

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: Ah, cool. Thanks

Comment: You could have used your favorite search engine to look up the answer.  Here's a good site: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

Comment: yeah, I saw that, but the ```new storage is allocated``` wasn't completely clear to me that it doesn't remove existing memory

Comment: *" And now I want to add 10000"* Beware that `reserve` will not add 10000 rectangles, it only prepares the vector so that 10000 can be quickly inserted later. You will still have to `emplace_back`, `insert` or otherwise add the rectangles.

Comment: This line on the linked page is pretty clear: **`reserve()` does not change the size of the vector.**  If `size()` was 10000 and you call `reserve(20000)` then `size()` is still 10000

Comment: Yeah thanks. The reserve is just there for when I do lots and lots of inserted rects, so it doesn't have to re-copy the vector to add it.

Comment: "yeah, I saw that, but the new storage is allocated wasn't completely clear to me that it doesn't remove existing memory" you should include such prior reseach results in the question. Currently the question looks as if you are just guessing

Comment: @peterwilson "*The reserve is just there for when I do lots and lots of inserted rects, so it doesn't have to re-copy the vector to add it*' - certainly for individual inserts, but just be aware that if you `reserve()` a value that is higher than the current `capacity()` than the inner array will be reallocated and the existing elements copied to the new memory.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau thats quite helpful. I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't delete any of the previous values. You can use it as you like (before or after the assignment of first 10000 values).